# Do I have to use Campden tablets every time I expose my wine to external factors?

Tags: wine, campden, sterilization

So, I'm pretty concerned about infections, seeing as my very first try ended in sauerkraut-smelling disappointment. I've got a gallon of quite sweet kiwi wine at about 16.5% ABV. The fermentation is now stopped by cold crashing followed by dose of Campden and potassium sorbate. However, the wine refuses to clear, so I was hoping to help it with some fining agents.

Normally I assumed that I should add Campden tablets anytime I open the carboy to prevent infections. However, that means I've added quite a lot already (I think 3-4 tablets for this one gallon over its lifetime) so would like to avoid adding more. Is it ok if I introduce the fining agents without a prophylactic Campden tablet? What about when bottling? Do I have to Campden my wine again to avoid accidental infection?

Answer (score 3):

You said you added Campden and potassium metabisulfate. Did you know they are the same thing? (Sometimes they are sodium metabisulfate, but do essentially the same thing)

Wine is not beer. Do not rush it. With grapes, it can take months for a wine to clear naturally. If you are in a hurry, try using some gelatin.

You do not need to add campden tablets every time you open the wine. You really should set it and forget it. Like for months before you bottle it. 3-4 tablets for a gallon is complete overkill and I worry you might make yourself sick drink this wine.

Yes, it's ok to put some fining agents in without more Campden tablets. But less fiddling and more time what probably what you need.

Comment: Hey, I actually meant potassium sorbate, not metabisulfite. Thanks for the answer otherwise! I might just give it some more time then.